# Auto-incremento não funcionando no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pgadmin4

Estou criando um sistema de controle de notas, que basicamente contém 3 tabelas no momento: Professores, Materias e Atividades. Estou no início do projeto, no qual somente fiz a view de cadastro de professor.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém na hora de inserir o registro, o ID (que está escondido no html) não está recebendo valor. Não retorna nenhum erro. Ao dar o Confirmar, somente ocorre um refresh na tela. Procurei dicas em alguns vídeos e fóruns mas nada que ajudou. Estou usando o PGAdmin. Segue abaixo o código da migration, controller e rotas.

**HTML**

```
@extends('cabecalho')

@extends('form')

@section('cont2')
    <form action="{{url('professor')}}" method="post">
        @csrf
        <input type="hidden" name="idprofessor">
        <label for="">Nome</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" placeholder="Nome do professor">
        <br><br>
        <label for="nome">Sobrenome</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="sobrenome" id="sobrenome" placeholder="Sobrenome do professor">
        <br><br>
        <label for="materia">Materia</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="materia" id="materia" placeholder="Matéria">
        <br><br>
        <label for="numero">Número</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="numero" id="numero" placeholder="(xx) x xxxx-xxxx" maxlength="12">
        <br><br>
        <label for="observacao">Observação</label>
        <br>
        <textarea name="observacao" id="observacao" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Confirmar">
    </form>
@stop
```

**Migration**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateProfessoresTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('professores', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nome',20);
            $table->string('sobrenome',50);
            $table->foreignId('materia_id',30);
            $table->string('numero',11);
            $table->longText('observacao');
        });
    }    
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('professores');
    }}
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Professor;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\Input;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class ProfessorController extends Controller
{
    public function create()
    {
        return view('professor.cadastro-professor');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'idprofessor' => 'required',
            'nome'        => 'required',
            'sobrenome'   => 'required',
            'materia'     => 'required',
            'telefone'    => 'required'
        ]);

        $professor = new Professor([
            'idprofessor' => $request->get('idprofessor'),
            'nome'        => $request->get('nome'),
            'sobrenome'   => $request->get('sobrenome'),
            'materia'     => $request->get('materia'),
            'telefone'    => $request->get('telefone')
        ]);

        $professor->save();

        return view('professor.cadastro-professor');
    }
```

**Rotas**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
Route::get('/', function() {
    return view('inicio');
});

Route::resource('Professor', 'ProfessorController');
Route::get('/cadastros', 'Controller@list');
Route::get('/cadastros/cadastro-professor', 'ProfessorController@create');
Route::post('/professor', 'ProfessorController@store');
```

Resumindo, o meu problema está com o ID que não está incrementando. Desde já agradeço, e peço desculpas também caso seja algo tosco.

Comment: Confirme se o request recebido no controller tem valor, com `dd($request->get('idprofessor'))`. Se sim, o problema deve estar na criação do professor, aonde você atribui o valor do `$request->idprofessor` a `idprofessor`, sendo que no banco de dados o campo se chama `id`

Answer (score 0):

O erro está no processo de enviar o `idprofessor` no objeto, pois se você quer autoincrement, você não deve carregar o atributo no objeto na camada do controller, considerando o método de store.

Como o controller deve ficar:

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Professor;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\Input;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ProfessorController extends Controller
{

    public function create()
    {
        return view('professor.cadastro-professor');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'nome'        => 'required',
            'sobrenome'   => 'required',
            'materia'     => 'required',
            'telefone'    => 'required'
        ]);

        $professor = new Professor([
            'nome'        => $request->get('nome'),
            'sobrenome'   => $request->get('sobrenome'),
            'materia'     => $request->get('materia'),
            'telefone'    => $request->get('telefone')
        ]);

        $professor->save();

        return view('professor.cadastro-professor');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você tambem pode inserir com mass assignment.

**View**

```
@extends('cabecalho')

@extends('form')

@section('cont2')
    <form action="{{url('professor')}}" method="post">
        @csrf
        <label for="">Nome</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" placeholder="Nome do professor">
        <br><br>
        <label for="nome">Sobrenome</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="sobrenome" id="sobrenome" placeholder="Sobrenome do professor">
        <br><br>
        <label for="materia">Materia</label>
        <br>
        <select name="materia_id">
            <option value='1'>Materia A</option>
            <option value='2'>Materia B</option>
            <option value='3'>Materia C</option>
            ...
        </select>
        <br><br>
        <label for="numero">Número</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="numero" id="numero" placeholder="(xx) x xxxx-xxxx" maxlength="12">
        <br><br>
        <label for="observacao">Observação</label>
        <br>
        <textarea name="observacao" id="observacao" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Confirmar">
    </form>
@stop
## Cabeçalhos ##
```

**Controller**

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'nome'        => 'required',
            'sobrenome'   => 'required',
            'materia_id'  => 'required',
            'numero'      => 'required'
        ]);
$professor = Professor::create($request->all());

if($professor){
    return redirect()->route('nome_rota');
}
```

**Model Professor**

```
protected $fillable = ['nome', 'sobrenome', 'materia_id', 'numero', 'observacao'];
```

Lembre-se que você deve ter matérias cadastradas no banco para traze-las até sua view, e depois salvar como Foreign Key.